# how to display data in listview?

Tags: android

Saver is a `Button`. When I click on it I want to get data from `EditText`, send it to another `Activity` and display it in `ListView`; but it display's nothing, I don't know what to do.

in mainActivity

```
if (v == saver) {
    String textData = reminder.getText().toString();

    Intent intent3 = new Intent(CreateActivity.this, ViewActivity.class);
    intent3.putExtra(textData, "key1");
    startActivity(intent3);
}
```

in list activity

```
ListView list;
ArrayList<String> taskslist;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view);
    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    taskslist = new ArrayList<String>();
    final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, taskslist);

    list.setAdapter(adapter);
    try {
        String recivedData;

        Intent intentt;
        intentt = getIntent();

        recivedData = intentt.getExtras().getString("key1");
        taskslist = intentt.getStringArrayListExtra(recivedData);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
    // adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should update your data set and then call `notifyDataSetChanged` to update your list, or populate your list before setting `adapter`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view);
    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    taskslist = new ArrayList<String>();
    taskslist = getIntent().getString("key1").getStringArrayListExtra(recivedData);
    final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, taskslist);

    list.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

or

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view);
    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    taskslist = new ArrayList<String>();
    final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, taskslist);

    list.setAdapter(adapter);
    try {
        String recivedData;

        Intent intentt;
        intentt = getIntent();

        recivedData = intentt.getExtras().getString("key1");
        taskslist = intentt.getStringArrayListExtra(recivedData);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
    adapter.setData(tasklist); // update data set
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: check the `Intent`'s extra. Is there any data in it?

Comment: String textData = reminder.getText().toString();

   Intent intent3 = new Intent(CreateActivity.this, ViewActivity.class);
   intent3.putExtra(textData, "key1");
   startActivity(intent3);

Comment: you should use `intent3.putExra("key1", textData);` instead of `intent3.putExra(textData, "key1");`

Answer (score 0):

instead of:

```
taskslist = intentt.getStringArrayListExtra(recivedData);
```

Try adding to taskslist and notifying the adapter:

```
taskslist.addAll(intentt.getStringArrayListExtra(recivedData));
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```